# PSEXEC Not executing command when password with " is specified

Tags: powershell, psexec

Issue:
  PSEXEC Executed from PS Script not running the command passed as argument when -p is specified along with a password that contains `"`.

Code:

```
$x = read-host -prompt 'Enter something:'

PSEXEC -u storeadmin -p ('"' + ($x -replace '"', '""') + '"') \\srXXX01 cmd /c TIME /T
```

Result:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
```

Expectation:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

XX:XX <-- THE ACTUAL TIME, then EXIT as I've invoked /C in CMD
```

Note:
This occurs only when password has `"` like `Anything:";K`. I've tested this on 100 different store machines. Only the stores with `"` has this abnormal behavior

Issue Details:
It exhibits the same behavior even when entered in the CLI on both Powershell and CMD directly.

Update:
The issue appears only when there's a " on the password. When there's a ", it just executes the `cmd` and not include `/C TIME /T`. I don't know why.

Comment: @mklement0 Let me try those suggestions first. But as of the "" issue, I have already made connection to the remote machine. The issue is that it's only running the command, not the parameters I've passed on to the command for some reason. Let me try this later @ the office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

It sounds like the issue is with `psexec` itself, whose command line parsing may be broken with passwords containing embedded `"` instances - see [this ancient blog post](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-and-complex-password_topic15565.html) - sounds like it never got fixed.

Your - suboptimal - options are:

- Change the password to not include double quotes (which may not be a bad idea in general, as other utilities may have trouble with such passwords too).
- Use the workaround suggested [here](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-command-with-double-quotes-in-password_topic15148.html): since the problem appears to be with passing additional *parameters*, put the command line a *batch file* - if the parameters vary, you can create this batch file dynamically and copy it to the remote machine for execution with `psexec`'s `-c` option.

---

Below is the **original answer, demonstrating various methods to escape double quotes.**

<sup>The question, which originally contained a multi-statement approach to escaping, was later updated with one of these methods.</sup>

---

If `psexec` expects embedded double quotes to be represented as `""`, do the following:

```
$x = read-host -prompt 'Enter something:'
PSEXEC -u storeadmin -p $($x -replace '"', '""') \\srXXX01 cmd /c TIME /T
```

With an input of `g=76"&,;Jl`, `psexec` will literally be passed `g=76""&,;Jl`.

If `psexec` ends up "eating" the embedded `""`, try the following:

```
PSEXEC -u storeadmin -p  ('"' + ($x -replace '"', '""') + '"') \\srXXX01 cmd /c TIME /T
```

If `psexec` requires `"` to be escaped as `\"` (which would be unusual for an MS program, which typically at least *also* support `""`), try:

```
PSEXEC -u storeadmin -p ('"' + ($x -replace '"', '\"') + '"') \\srXXX01 cmd /c TIME /T
```

Comment: Yup I know powershell will. But PSEXEC still won't be able to handle it. I've tried and tested

Comment: Sample password. g=76"&,;Jl

PSEXEC chokes on the "

Comment: @LuigiMackenzieC.Brito: Please see my update; one of the 3 variants - `""` without outer quotes, `""` with outer quotes, `\"` with outer quotes - hopefully works.

Comment: @Mklemn. I added an update on the question. I'm using your -replace method now. I still can't get over the "glitch" though

Comment: @LuigiMackenzieC.Brito: I've updated my answer again. In the future, please don't retrofit your question with pieces from existing answers (or at least don't do so without comment), because it can make those answers pointless.

Comment: @mk

After intensive research myself. I'll have to agree with you and consider this as the only possible answer there is for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not with psexec command line parsing. The issue is that your password contains a character with a special meaning in cmd. You need to escape such characters with ^. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: Asked 5 years, 7 months ago. But still, thank you